# simple view in backbone not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I try to make a simple view in backbone, on button press (with class .buy-products) it must trigger the 'buyProducts' method, but it doesn't , help plz

```
var CurrProducts = Backbone.View.extend({

        events: {
            "click .buy-products": 'buyProducts'
        },

        buyProducts: function() {
            console.log("working1");
        },

        render: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });
    var test = new CurrProducts();
    test.render()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first bind the backbone view to element on the page that is containing the .buy-product button.

For simplicity sake you can bind it to the body:

```
var CurrProducts = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "body",
    //rest of your code
});
```

http://backbonejs.org/#View-el